# Bootstrap Collapse close div when other open

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with this. All of the divs open and close when you click on their buttons. But what I want them to do is the following: If one div is open and I click a button to open the next I want the open one to close and the new one to open if that makes sense. Here is a link to the code:

https://codepen.io/iamdesfranco/pen/QNVqLO

```
<div class="container-fluid hidden-xs">
   <div class="row blue">
      <!-- Block One -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 fixed-height-twofive">
         <div class="text-center vertical-allign">
            <h3>Background Image</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Block Two -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 fixed-height-twofive">
         <div class="text-center vertical-allign">
            <h3>Personal Involvement</h3>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
               consectetur adipiscing elit,
               sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#aPInvolveD" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aPInvolveD" >
            See More
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Block Three -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 fixed-height-twofive">
         <div class="text-center vertical-allign">
            <h3>Background Image</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- ALL ACCORDIONS FOR DESKTOP AND TABLET
   =========================================== -->
<!-- ACCORDION 1 -->
<div class="collapse blue" id="aPInvolveD">
   <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Bobby Rangecroft</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna<br />
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
         esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint<br />
         occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia<br />
         deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <br />
      <h3>Dick Bruyns</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna<br />
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
         esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint<br />
         occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia<br />
         deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- ACCORDION 2 -->
<div class="collapse blue " id="aClientD">
   <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Bobby Rangecroft</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna<br />
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
         esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint<br />
         occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia<br />
         deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <br />
      <h3>Dick Bruyns</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna<br />
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
         esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint<br />
         occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia<br />
         deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- ACCORDION 3 -->
<div class="collapse blue " id="aTestD">
   <div class="text-center">
      <h3>Bobby Rangecroft</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna<br />
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
         esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint<br />
         occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia<br />
         deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
      <br />
      <h3>Dick Bruyns</h3>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
         sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna<br />
         aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
         ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<br />
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
         esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint<br />
         occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia<br />
         deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- ROW TWO
   ==============-->
<div class="container-fluid blue hidden-xs">
   <div class="row">
      <!-- Block One -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 fixed-height-twofive">
         <div class="text-center vertical-allign">
            <h3>Our Clients</h3>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
               consectetur adipiscing elit,
               sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#aClientD" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aClientD">
            See More
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Block Two -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 fixed-height-twofive">
         <div class="text-center vertical-allign">
            <h3>Background Image</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Block Three -->
      <div class="col-sm-4 fixed-height-twofive">
         <div class="text-center vertical-allign">
            <h3>Testimonials</h3>
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
               consectetur adipiscing elit,
               sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#aTestD" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="aTestD">
            See More
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
 $('.collapse').not($(this)).collapse('hide');
});
```

demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMqVOY

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the collapsable divs in a parent div

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
```

Then wrap each one in a panel div

```
<div class="panel">
```

And then reference the parent for each toggle button

```
parent="#accordion"
```

https://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/BKOwzZ